# How to get visibility into completion queue on C++ gRPC server

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

*Note: Help with the immediate problem would be great, but mostly I'm looking for advice on troubleshooting gRPC timing issues in general (this isn't my first such issue).*

I am adding a new server streaming service to a C++ module which has an existing server streaming service, and the two appear to be conflicting.  Specifically, the completion queue `Next()` call on the server is crashing intermittently after the C# client calls `Cancel()` on the cancellation token for one of the services.  This doesn't happen if I run each service independently.

On the client, I get this at the response stream `MoveNext()` call:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Shutdown has already been called
  Source=Grpc.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.CompletionQueueSafeHandle.BeginOp()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.CallSafeHandle.StartReceiveMessage(IReceivedMessageCallback callback)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCallBase`2.ReadMessageInternalAsync()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.ClientResponseStream`2.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyModule.Connection.<DoSubscriptionReceives>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\snip\Connection.cs:line 67
```

On the server, I get this at the completion queue `next()` call:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
core_cq_tag->**** was 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

The stack trace:

```
    MyModule.exe!grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void * * tag, bool * ok, gpr_timespec deadline) Line 59  C++
>   MyModule.exe!grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::Next(void * * tag, bool * ok) Line 176 C++
...snip...
```

It appears something is being added to the queue after shutdown.  The difficulty is I have little visibility into what is being added into the queue and in what order.

I'm trying to write a server-side interceptor to log all requests & responses, but there seems to be no documentation.  So far, poking through the API hasn't gotten me very far.  **Is there any documentation available on wiring up an interceptor in C++?  Or, are there other approaches for troubleshooting timing conflicts between services?**

*Windows 11, Grpc.Core 1.27*

*What I've tried:*
*I first played with the `GRPC_TRACE` & `GRPC_VERBOSITY` environment variables.  I was able to get some unhelpful output from the client, but nothing from the server.  Of course, there's been lots of debugging, stripping the client & server down to barebones, disabling keep alives, ensuring we aren't using deadlines, having the services share a cancellation token, etc.*

Update: I have found that the crash only happens when the client is run from an NUnit test.  In that environment, the completion queue is getting more hits on `Next()`, but I'm still trying to figure out where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 1.27 the version you are using? That seems pretty old.. There might have been fixes since then.

For using the C++ server interception API, I think you would find this very useful - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/0f2a0f5fc9b9e9b9c98d227d16575d106f1e8d43/test/cpp/end2end/server_interceptors_end2end_test.cc#L48

One suggestion I have is to run the code another sanitizers https://github.com/google/sanitizers to make sure that we don't have a heap-use-after-free type bug.

I would also check for API misuse issues. (If you had posted the code, I could've given a look to see if anything seems weird..)

Comment: You are correct; 1.27 is very old.  I'm stuck with that in production, but I did test locally with the latest and got a very similar crash - also on completion queue next().

Thank you for the API example link!  That appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  Trying it out now...